# How to insert items into existing array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Assume I have two arrays as below

```
array:2 [
  0 => {#1995
    +"id": 6
    +"sales_target_amount": "30000.00"
  }
  1 => {#1996
    +"id": 10
    +"sales_target_amount": "1000.00"
  }
]
```

second array

```
array:2 [
  0 => {#1994
    +"sales_total": "4165.80"
    +"staff_id": 6
  }
  1 => {#1513
    +"sales_total": "1335.60"
    +"staff_id": 10
  }
]
```

I'm trying to insert the first array `sales_target_amount` into the second array if the `id` is matched to the `staff_id`.

code

```
  $sum = array_merge($second_array[],$firs_array);
```

The code above will merge the two array together but not insert the items based on the id.

Expected Result

```
array:2 [
      0 => {#1994
        +"sales_total": "4165.80"
        +"staff_id": 6
        +"sales_target_amount": "30000.00"
      }
      1 => {#1513
        +"sales_total": "1335.60"
        +"staff_id": 10
        +"sales_target_amount": "1000.00"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: you want to merge two arrays on a condition, but where you have put the condition? I believe you would have opted for traversing both array and merge them if id matches. Hope you may know that much programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet, please see inline doc for explanation

```
$arr = [
    0 => ["sales_total" => "4165.80", "staff_id" => 6],
    1 => ["sales_total" => "1335.60", "staff_id" => 10],
];
$arr1 = [
    0 => ["id" => 6, "sales_target_amount" => "30000.00"],
    1 => ["id" => 10, "sales_target_amount" => "1000.00"],
];
//NULL to return complete arrays or objects and staff id will be key
$arr = array_column($arr, null, 'staff_id');
// mapping id sales target amount combination
$temp = array_column($arr1, 'sales_target_amount', 'id');
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key]['sales_target_amount'] = $temp[$key]; // putting sales_target_amount for id
}
```

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

[**Demo Link**](https://3v4l.org/VQEnU).

Answer (score 0):

Use hashed map to group values by `staff_id`

```
<?php
$arr1 = [
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'sales_target_amount' => '30000.00'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 10,
        'sales_target_amount' => '1000.00'
    ]
];

$arr2 = [
    [
        'sales_total' => '4165.80',
        'staff_id' => 6
    ],
    [
        'sales_total' => '1335.60',
        'staff_id' => 10
    ]
];

$results = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    $results[$value['id']] = [
        'sales_target_amount' => $value['sales_target_amount']
    ];
}

foreach ($arr2 as $value) {
    $results[$value['staff_id']] = array_merge($results[$value['staff_id']], $value);
}

print_r(array_values($results));
```

Answer (score 0):

array_merge() do not work with multidimensional array.
Try to use array_merge_recursive().

And you not need use square brackets in this context.
Run function just like

```php
$sum = array_merge_recursive($second_array, $firs_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort answer using [this library](https://packagist.org/packages/minwork/array)

```php
$array = array_merge_recursive(
  Arr::flattenSingle(Arr::group($array1, 'id')), 
  Arr::flattenSingle(Arr::group($array2, 'staff_id'))
);
```

What it does underneath is to first group your arrays by column you want them merged by. Then because every element in group will have only one corresponding array (cause they are grouped by unique id) flatten those groups to build array with elements like `id => array_with_that_id`. And then merge those flattened groups by keys which in these case are ids.

Overall this will produce

```php
Array (
  [6] => Array (
    [id] => 6
    [sales_total] => 4165.8
    [staff_id] => 6
    [sales_target_amount] => 30000
  )
  [10] => Array (
    [id] => 10
    [sales_total] => 1335.6
    [staff_id] => 10
    [sales_target_amount] => 1000
  ) 
)
```